# "iw" command not working in Qprocess in Qt Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c++, qt, qml, ubuntu-14.04, qprocess

i am trying to run the following command with `QProcess` :

```
QString cmd = QString("iw wlan0 scan | grep dBm");
QProcess *qProc = new QProcess();
qProc->start(cmd);
qProc->waitForFinished();
```

and getting error :

> "Usage:    iw [options] dev  scan [-u] [freq *] [ies ] [ssid* |passive]
>
> Scan on the given frequencies and probe for the given SSIDs
>      (or wildcard if not given) unless passive scanning is requested.
>      If -u is specified print unknown data in the scan results.
>      Specified (vendor) IEs must be well-formed.

Options:

```
    --debug     enable netlink debugging
```

but the command is working fine in terminal...please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

QProcess runs one process, to execute a command you can run *sh* and pass the command after *-c*:

```
QString cmd = QString("iw wlan0 scan | grep dBm");
QProcess sh;
sh.start("sh", QStringList() << "-c" << cmd);
sh.waitForFinished();
QByteArray out = sh.readAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to run such commands with `QProcess` is to put it in a shell script and call it like :

```
QProcess process;
process.start("/bin/sh", QStringList()<< "myScript.sh");
```

You can also pass it as an argument to your bash or shell after `-c` :

```
QProcess process;
process.start("/bin/sh", QStringList()<<"-c"<<"iw wlan0 scan | grep dBm" );
```

A more general solution which is independent of your shell or bash system is using to objects of `QProcess`:

```
QProcess process1
QProcess process2;

process1.setStandardOutputProcess(&process2);

process1.start("iw wlan0 scan");
process2.start("grep dBm");
process2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);

process1.waitForStarted();

process2->waitForFinished();
```